# When using split() with jsonpath - how can I detect/intercept an empty json string in order to skip processing, or, handle exception?

Tags: json, java-8, apache-camel, jbossfuse

***QUESTION:***

When using split() with jsonpath - how can I detect/intercept an empty json string in order to skip processing,  or, otherwise, handle the exception thrown?

***Here is sample RouteBuilder/configure() method shown, below...***

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    ...

    from("direct:thingA")
        .setBody(constant(emptyJsonString))  <== testing empty json string
        .to("direct:thingB");

    from("direct:thingB")
        .split()
        .jsonpath("$.container[*]")   <== Exception when empty!
        .streaming()
        .parallelProcessing()
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) exchange.getIn().getBody();
            exchange.getIn().setBody("...fielda=" + map.get("fielda") + "...fieldb=" + map.get("fieldb") + "...fieldc=" + map.get("fieldc"));
            }
        })
        .to("wmq:queue:mylocalqueue?jmsMessageType=Text&exchangePattern=InOnly");
}
```

**the exception thrown when the jsonString is "empty"...**

```
Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.ExpressionEvaluationException: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Missing property in path $['container']
    at org.apache.camel.jsonpath.JsonPathExpression.evaluate(JsonPathExpression.java:83)[534:org.apache.camel.camel-jsonpath:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ExpressionAdapter.evaluate(ExpressionAdapter.java:36)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.createProcessorExchangePairs(Splitter.java:113)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:231)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.process(Splitter.java:108)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:192)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:76)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)[:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)[:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Missing property in path $['container']
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PathToken.handleObjectProperty(PathToken.java:72)[531:com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path:2.1.0]
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PropertyPathToken.evaluate(PropertyPathToken.java:77)[531:com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path:2.1.0]
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.RootPathToken.evaluate(RootPathToken.java:62)[531:com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path:2.1.0]
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:53)[531:com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path:2.1.0]
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:61)[531:com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path:2.1.0]
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:187)[531:com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path:2.1.0]
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:345)[531:com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.jsonpath.JsonPathEngine.read(JsonPathEngine.java:75)[534:org.apache.camel.camel-jsonpath:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.jsonpath.JsonPathExpression.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpression.java:106)[534:org.apache.camel.camel-jsonpath:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.jsonpath.JsonPathExpression.evaluate(JsonPathExpression.java:76)[534:org.apache.camel.camel-jsonpath:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    ... 28 more
2017-09-06 11:46:28,245 | WARN  | 14 - timer://foo | TimerConsumer                    | 232 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | Error processing exchange. Exchange[ID-AAXA22A747-64856-1504708189791-3-2]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.ExpressionEvaluationException - com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Missing property in path $['container']]
org.apache.camel.ExpressionEvaluationException: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Missing property in path $['container']
    at org.apache.camel.jsonpath.JsonPathExpression.evaluate(JsonPathExpression.java:83)[534:org.apache.camel.camel-jsonpath:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ExpressionAdapter.evaluate(ExpressionAdapter.java:36)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.createProcessorExchangePairs(Splitter.java:113)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:231)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.process(Splitter.java:108)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:192)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:76)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)[:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)[:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Missing property in path $['container']
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PathToken.handleObjectProperty(PathToken.java:72)[531:com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path:2.1.0]
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PropertyPathToken.evaluate(PropertyPathToken.java:77)[531:com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path:2.1.0]
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.RootPathToken.evaluate(RootPathToken.java:62)[531:com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path:2.1.0]
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:53)[531:com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path:2.1.0]
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:61)[531:com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path:2.1.0]
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:187)[531:com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path:2.1.0]
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:345)[531:com.jayway.jsonpath.json-path:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.camel.jsonpath.JsonPathEngine.read(JsonPathEngine.java:75)[534:org.apache.camel.camel-jsonpath:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.jsonpath.JsonPathExpression.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpression.java:106)[534:org.apache.camel.camel-jsonpath:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.jsonpath.JsonPathExpression.evaluate(JsonPathExpression.java:76)[534:org.apache.camel.camel-jsonpath:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    ... 28 more
```

*** fwiw, an example of non-empty jsonString...***

```
/*  non-empty json structure...
{
    "container": [
    {
        "fielda": "...this is fieldA value(0)...",
        "fieldb": "...this is fieldB value(0)...",
        "fieldc": "...this is fieldC value(0)..."
    },
    {
        "fielda": "...this is fieldA value(1)...",
        "fieldb": "...this is fieldB value(1)...",
        "fieldc": "...this is fieldC value(1)..."
    }
}
*/
```

Comment: You can try to turn on suppressExceptions on jsonpath: http://camel.apache.org/jsonpath

Comment: Thanks, Claus!  That's solves the issue!  :-)